# How can I mosaic raster data which have different number of bands ( 3 and 4)?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-10.1, image-mosaic, band

I would like to mosaic 100 raster data.
several raster data's band are 3, though last data have 4 bands.

How can I mosaic raster data which have different number of bands??

If somebody knows how to solve this issue, let me know.

OS:Windows XP
GIS: ArcInfo 10.1  or QGIS1.8.0

Comment: What do the bands *mean*? Unless they are measuring comparable things (such as the same spectral intervals), attempting such a mosaic may be nonsensical.

Comment: Still the same issue pops up, have look at the result with virtual database [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Odhrk.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Odhrk.jpg)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer, more of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to build a virtual Dataset with `gdalbuildvrt`, where you can specify to add an alpha channel with the `-addalpha` parameter for the 3-band-datasets.

http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html

Alternatively you can use gdal_translate:

```
gdal_translate -of vrt -expand rgba
```

Or have a look at the last example of the manpage of gdal_translate:

http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html